# Slowing time, but not the program

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game, where when a player steps outside the screen, the level starts. I wish to show an image of "LEVEL 1" before the game starts, yet the program shows the image too quickly. My framerate is at 60.

I am wondering if there is a way to delay time for about 5 seconds during the screen blitting but after it resumes to it's normal pace. The problem for me with the `pygame.time.delay()` and wait stuff is that is slows the entire program down.

Is there a easier way?

EDIT______ CODE

```
 #START OF LEVEL 1
    if level1:

        screen.blit(level1_image,background_position)
        pygame.time.delay(500)
        level1yay = True
    if level1yay:

        screen.blit(background,background_position)

#Flip the Display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(time)

#Quit
pygame.quit()
```

The first image is not displayed and goes directly to the second image

Comment: So you did try to show the image, then delay the program for 5 seconds?

Comment: I did, however it didn't work, it paused my entire program and the image for some reason never actualy shows up.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a timer and keep track of the time. when the timer reaches the delay you want you can do something.

In the example below I set up the timer and I set the level1yay to true only once the timer has reached the delay value.

I added a condition canexit so the game doesn't terminate on the first loop. I assumed that the condition for "if level1: " has been set somewhere else.

```
mytimer = pygame.time.Clock() #creates timer
time_count = 0 #will be used to keep track of the time
mydelay = 5000 # will delay the main game by 5 seconds
canexit = False

#updates  timer
    mytimer.tick()
    time_count += mytimer.get_time()
#check if mydelay has been reached
    if  time_count >= mydelay:
        level1yay = True
        canexit = True

#START OF LEVEL 1
    if level1:
        screen.blit(level1_image,background_position)

    if level1yay:
        screen.blit(background,background_position)

#Flip the Display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(time)

 #Quit
 if canexit ==  True:
    pygame.quit()
```

EDIT TO INCLUDE ACTIONS PRIOR TO ENTERING LEVEL1:

```
mytimer = pygame.time.Clock() #creates timer
time_count = 0 #will be used to keep track of the time
mydelay = 5000 # will delay the main game by 5 seconds
canexit = False
start_menu = True # to start with the start menu rather than level1

#Do something before level 1
    if start_menu == True:
        ... do stuff
        if start_menu end:
             level1 = True
             time_count = 0

#START OF LEVEL 1
    if level1 == True:
    #updates  timer
        mytimer.tick() # start's ticking the timer
        time_count += mytimer.get_time() # add's the time since the last tick to time_count
    #check if mydelay has been reached
        if  time_count >= mydelay:
            level1 = False # so that you do not enter level1 again (even though this is redundant here since you will exit the game at the end of the loop... see canexit comment)
            level1yay = True # so that you can enter level1yay
            canexit = True # so that the game terminates at the end of the game loop 
            screen.blit(level1_image,background_position)

    if level1yay:
        screen.blit(background,background_position)

#Flip the Display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(time)

 #Quit
 if canexit ==  True:
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Just a question. Lets just say that a player has to do something to get to this level 1 screen. Wouldn't time then be unpredictable because you don't know when the player will enter. Also do I have to put all those above variables before or after the loop.

Comment: Hi, I would put the variables before the loop otherwise they will be reset each time the game loop is called and time_count will never reach the mydelay value since time_count will be reset to 0.   I terms of getting into level 1 after having entered the game for a while (say you have a menu screen), then you could add a condition so that when the player leaves this menu screen the time_count is reset to 0. Since the mytimer.tick() get's the time elapsed since the last tick it should work.

Comment: I have just edited my answer to give you an idea... I can't exactly remember what the tick and get_time() do for sure, so maybe that setting your time_count to 0 when leaving the "start menu", or whatever is done before level1, is not even necessary. See http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html for more info. In my class based game I'm using these timers for a lot of things like allowing the player to attack only once every 1 second or delaying sprite animations... I haven't had any problems with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will really work, but you could try displaying the same image of "LEVEL 1" multiple times in a row, so it appears to stay around longer, but the program itself is never actually delayed.

Comment: I tried that, but at 60 frames per second, I cant put up to 300 images on per second. It would take up the speed, and it would be messy. I could do a for loop, but there are definitely easier ways.

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.time.wait(5000)` is a delay of 5 seconds, 500 is half a second.  You did set the level1 variable to True just before this code fragment, right?

Comment: Yes I do set it to true. I tried that and it still did not work, My entire program just freezes.